# Javascript image collision

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision

Okay so I have 2 images, player and enemy. I have created a function to check for collision between both the images. I have tried to get them to collide like you would see on a 2d platformer but instead of stopping the player for going over the image; as soon as they collide the player image freeze in the same x&y co ord. Here is there code I have.

//FUNCTION

```
function CollisionCheck(Img1, Img2, Obj1, Obj2, width){
    if(Obj1.x < Obj2.x + width && Obj1.x + width > Obj2.x && Obj1.y < Obj2.y + width && Obj1.y + width > Obj2.y){
        colliding = true;
        return;
    }else{
        colliding = false;
        return;   
    }
};
```

//WHILE LOOP TO CHECK FOR COLLISION (THIS COULD BE THE PROBLEM)

```
CollisionCheck(playerImg, enemyImg, player, enemy, 32);
    while(colliding){
        var x = player.x;
        var y = player.y;
        player.x = x;
        player.y = y;
        if(colliding = false){
            return;   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop is assigning to colliding instead of doing a comparison (= vs ===). Also, the assignment to player.x and player.y are not doing anything.